# Process Before Publishing a ready Kivy App in Playstore?

Tags: android, python, google-play-services, kivy

I already did `buildozer android debug` and have the `.apk` file installed and works fine, at least tested for one/two devices. This is also with the semi-default `buildozer.spec`, for example : the domain name is still `org.test` but with the name of the app is adjusted.

> With this `.apk` file (after `buildozer android debug` process), is
>   this the one that is ready to be uploaded to playstore? or there is
>   still some other (technical) preparations?

I know that we may do beta test first before making it public. This is my first  time coding an app with intention to publish it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `release` version of your apk file before uploading to the Play Store. The `debug` version is just for testing on your phone. To create a `release` version and upload the app, you just have to follow these steps.

1. Create a Key

```
$ mkdir ~/keystores/
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/keystores/<your-new-key>.keystore -alias <your-key-alias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

2. Export some variables

```
$ export P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE=~/keystores/<your-new-key>.keystore
 $ export P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWD=android
 $ export P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS_PASSWD=android
 $ export P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS=<your-key-alias>
```

3.  Make release apk

```
 $ cd <your-project-folder>
 $ buildozer -v android release
```

4. Finally, optimize it

```
 $ ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -v 4 ./bin/Your-App-0.1-release.apk ./bin/Your-App-0.1-release-optimized.apk
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if don't have released version of the `.apk` file, using only the debug-version, then I would not be able to upload it to playstore..?

Comment: You're welcome. And no, you won't be able to upload the debug version. It will ask you to create a Release version.

Comment: Hey @DipanshuJuneja silly question, but where do I get the key values for <your-new-key>? Or do I literally have to type that in? I.e do I copy exactly (not change anything) that you have added?

Comment: Wow. Such a trivial question, yet so much points. Well structured answer though ).