# Steps to make a releasable apk to play store by buildozer

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I finally finished my android app and I wanted to release it to play store. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48228135/11005513) explains how to do it but I have a question.Where do I get the key and key alias from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose whatever value you want. Try it and see what happens.